# Modal is not appearing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the bootstrap 4 modal. But its not working properly, when the button is clicked the modal dont appears. It just appears a gray brackground and then this background disappears. Do you know where can be the issue?

**//before close the tag `<body>` are the imports**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The input to open the modal is inside a form:

**// html**

```
  <input type="submit" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Send"/>
        </form>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**// js**

```
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using input type="submit" to show modal Your site will be reloaded before modal show.Try to change input type="submit" to input type="button" bro.

Comment: Thanks, now modal appears, but the buttons dont appear. Do you know what can be the issue for the buttons are not shown?

Comment: The buttons inside modal-footer div dont appear but if i remove the buttons and put some test text like "test" the text appears, but the buttos not.

Comment: Because when modal show, all old elements will be overridden by the modal box. You can use the jquery append to push that input into the modal class.